# mybatis annotation batch insert

Tags: mybatis, spring-mybatis

I am using spring-mybatis.

What is the best way to insert thousands in batch?

I am currently using @InsertProvider and loop through thousands records and insert into DB.

The current way will cause connection issue if the insert is in millions.

Example:

```
@Insert({
            "<script>",
            "insert into mybatis_demo (name, age)",
            "values ",
            "<foreach  collection='dmoList' item='dmo' separator=','>",
            "( #{dmo.name,jdbcType=VARCHAR}, #{dmo.age,jdbcType=INTEGER})",
            "</foreach>",
            "</script>"
    })
    int insertBatch(@Param("dmoList") List<MybatisDemoDMO> dmoList);
```

Comment: Your current approach is called [multi-row insert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insert_(SQL)#Multirow_inserts) which is not suitable for handling many rows. See this [FAQ](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-code-a-batch-insert) for how to perform JDBC API's batch operation. [Here](https://github.com/jeffgbutler/mybatis-cockroach-demo) is a complete demo project using spring-boot.

Comment: There's limit that the database engine and the JDBC driver impose, in terms of the length of the SQL statement and also in the total number of JDBC parameters. You should batch them into subsets of a specific size (let's say 100 rows at a time). I've found that going beyond 100 rows at a time only marginally improves performance. "Mileage may vary", though.

Comment: In my opinion @ave's response is the best approach (and it's also simple).

Comment: @ave, the mybatis cockcrachdb addAccounts is the correct way to do it? Because it looks like multiple insert: for (Account account : accounts) {
            batchMapper.insertAccount(account);
        }

Comment: @Alvin In the [config](https://github.com/jeffgbutler/mybatis-cockroach-demo/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/cockroachdemo/MyBatisConfiguration.java), you can see `batchMapper` uses `ExecutorType.BATCH` which tells MyBatis to perform [JDBC batch operation](https://www.baeldung.com/jdbc-batch-processing). In a real-world application, it's usually better to flush statements every X items (finding out the best X for your app requires testing). There also are DB-specific config that affects performance like `rewriteBatchedStatements` in MySQL.